# Access Hadoop on server from python

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, thrift

First of all, I need to say that I am a girl who knows very little about remote server. A lot of similar questions asked here is very difficult for me to understand. So I come to ask.

My task is to generate a script which helps me fetch some data from a server.
The data is stored in Hadoop. Usually I log in the server with a user name and a temporary password. I run 'hive' clauses on the server. After I get all the data on the server, I download it. Then on my computer, I manipulate the data on my own computer with Python.

Now I hope to do this with one Python script.
I find thrift package, but don't know how to begin to understand.
I wonder should I install hive on my computer, then use sys to run hive. Or should I log in the server and run hive on the server in my script?
In any case, can thrift help me log in the server?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Although Thrift can surely help you, it is recommended to use a more higher-level client. They are usually well-tested and will keep all (or most of) the low level stuff away from you. In particular, [HBase](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-use-the-hbase-thrift-interface-part-1/) looks promising in your case. I'd recommend to have a look at that one, and to compare it with the Hadoop Python Thrift Client described in [this tutorial](http://www.openscg.com/2013/08/hadoop-thrift-tutorial/).

Comment: Thanks very much. I have been too busy these months. I finally figure out that our sever should firstly support Thrift. It doesn't. So I didn't follow this thread. Anyway,Thanks very much. Hope your tutorial will help me in future work.